# Nutritional Guidelines

Tags: nutrition

Where can I find FDA nutritional guidelines that are used for Nutritional Facts on packaged foods?

Based on 2000 calorie diet

Total fat
Sat fat
Cholesteral
Sodium
Carbohydrate
Protein

**Daily g or mg for each of the items above?**

I can find examples with % but cannot find what total is used.
Like 7% is rounded from some number.

Comment: Down votes what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[National Institutes of Health](https://www.dsld.nlm.nih.gov/dsld/dailyvalue.jsp)

Daily Values for nutrients in a 2,000 Calorie diet:

- Total fat = 65 g
- Sat fat = 20 g
- Cholesteral = 300 mg
- Sodium = 2,400 mg
- Carbohydrate = 300 g
- Protein = 50 g